# (stuck!) Help understanding regular expressions/backreferences in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to make a MVC framework with a front controller and routing system.

The routing system works by defining paths like this...

```
$route->add('{controller}/{action}'); // default path
$route->add('admin/{controller}/{action}'); // admin path
```

To do this I am first building up a regular expression from the predefined routes.

Then I take the URL query string (e.g. home/index) and see if it matches the regular expression using `preg_match();`

Here is the example code...

```
$route = 'admin/{controller}/{action}';
$url = 'admin/controller/action';

echo $route . '<br>';
$route = preg_replace('/\//', '\\/', $route); // repaces '/' with '\/'
echo $route . '<br>';
$route = preg_replace('/{([a-z]+)}/', '(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)', $route); // for each path segment in curly {} gets replaced with a regular expression and named according to what is in the braces
echo $route . '<br>';
$route = '/^' . $route . '$/i'; // encapsulating the reg_exp
echo $route . '<br>';

preg_match($route, $url, $matches);

echo '<pre>', print_r($matches);
```

This outputs the following code... you can see how the regular expression is built from the path I defined... {controller}/{action}

[image]

Now the part that I simply do NOT understand is this:

```
?P<\1>
```

**How is this working so that the output array keys are named after {controller} and {action}??** I cant find ANY information on this syntax and am thoroughly confused!

Comment: Most of the MVC are using htaccess to achieve controller/action/parameters

Comment: Did you try a right-click/display source?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Fil, that's a good point. The reason I am tackling regular expressions is because I hope it can give me more flexible routing options for my urls.

Comment: Casimir could you please clarify? This is my own source code.

Comment: @Casimir I see what you mean, it is displaying in the source! I need a good explination about just how this is all working though... clear as mud at the moment.

Comment: In your browser (where your `echo`s and `print_r` are displayed), right click with your mouse, and select something like *view page source code* (to display the html code and look at it).

Comment: Have you tried putting the regex into a regex tester to see what it is doing? https://regex101.com/

Comment: This regex tester looks better then the other one I tried... going to do some tests now, thanks so much for the link!

Comment: @ Doug, this site is absolutely brilliant, a real life saver!

Comment: I guess you already figured it out by now.  My guess is that the `<\1>` uses the first capture group to print `<controller>`. But which would be ignored by a browser because it's an unrecognized tag.